# Is there an oracle that separates two complexity classes known to be equal?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles

We know that there exist two oracles $A$ and $B$ such that $P^A=NP^A$ and $P^B\neq NP^B$, this implies the obstacle of proving $P\neq NP$ using diagonalization.  I just wonder if there exist two complexity classes, say $A$ and $B$ and oracle $O$ such that $A=B$ but $A^O\neq B^O$?

I am not sure if it is a research-level problem. So don't hesitate to close it if not.

Thanks.

Comment: Then it means $P\ne NP$, otherwise, how can an oracle separate them?

Comment: OK, here "the same" means they are shown to be same, but may use completely different definitions, like $IP=PSPACE$.

Comment: I suggest that you change the question to reflect this.

Comment: related: [1](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/504/complexity-class-separation-in-the-presence-of-relativization-barriers)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have IP = PSPACE = PPSPACE, where PPSPACE is the "probabilistic polynomial space," as defined by Papadimitriou's [Games Against Nature](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0022000085900455).

However, relative to a random oracle O, we have IP<sup>O</sup> ≠ PSPACE<sup>O</sup> = PPSPACE<sup>O</sup> with probability 1. (See [The Random Oracle Hypothesis is False](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~chang/papers/roh/).)

Another example: let the assumption be false; that is, if A=B the A<sup>O</sup> = B<sup>O</sup> for **any** oracle O and **all** complexity classes A and B. The contrapositive will say: If A<sup>O</sup> ≠ B<sup>O</sup>, then A ≠ B. Specially, since there exists an oracle O such that P<sup>O</sup> ≠ NP<sup>O</sup>, then P ≠ N, and a long-standing problem is solved!!!

Obviously, this reasoning has no basis, and I believe it can be refuted as such.

**PS:** When we use the "=" sign with respect to sets, we mean that every element of one set is also a member of the other set, and vice versa. However, the sets might have totally different definitions. In the axiomatic set theory, this is called the [axiom of extensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). The reason of "IP = PSPACE but IP<sup>O</sup> ≠ PSPACE<sup>O</sup> with probability 1 for a random oracle O" is exactly this: While IP and PSPACE are externally identical, their internal structure is quite different.

Comment: i.e. relativization is not defined for languages but for specific machines and depends on the structure of the machine. :)